# Set directives options globally

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How to set the values of directive options such as (restrict, replace) with default values instead of re-configure them for each directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that returns a function that creates the directive with your predefined options

Confused?

```
function predefined_options_for_directive(options) {
  return function() {
    return Object.assign({
      restrict: 'A'
    }, options);
  }
}

angular.module("myApp", []).directive("myDirective",
    predefined_options_for_directive({
      template: "<h1>Yolo</h1>"
    })).controller("main", function($scope){
  $scope.testVar = 2;
})
```

You can avoid having the function as a global with a module bundler like browserify or webpack

***note that object.assign will probably need a polyfill***

example [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxmQQd)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no way to do that. Anyways, what's the problem writing those options in each directive? Think that this makes your code easier to understand.

Comment: this should be definitely a comment

Comment: From code perspective it is not good to repeat the same code while you can configure it globally !